# How do I check how many unique member object in an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Assuming that I have an array object as below. I want to push the number of members of each unique `groupId` into an array

```
let array = []
let arrObj = [
              {groupId: 32, userId: 61, fullname: "Sonia M Russell", email: "sonia647@yahoo.com"},
              {groupId: 32, userId: 63, fullname: "zzzzdf Russell", email: "sonia647@yahoo.com"},
              {groupId: 43, userId: 65, fullname: "sdfsdf", email: "sonia647@yahoo.com"},
              {groupId: 59, userId: 67, fullname: "sdfdsfdf", email: "sonia647@yahoo.com"}
]
```

```
// Expected output
array = [2, 1 ,1]
```

Because groupId repeats 2 times, that means there are 2 members in group 32. And so on.

I'm not really experienced with JavaSript.

Comment: Wouldn't that be better to have an indexed counter? What if the first and fourth entry were the same? You want to start the counting over or count together?

Comment: This is just an example, the data is actually retrieved from the database and all of them sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let array = []
let arrObj = [
  {groupId: 32, userId: 61, fullname: "Sonia M Russell", email: "sonia647@yahoo.com"},
  {groupId: 32, userId: 63, fullname: "zzzzdf Russell", email: "sonia647@yahoo.com"},
  {groupId: 43, userId: 65, fullname: "sdfsdf", email: "sonia647@yahoo.com"},
  {groupId: 59, userId: 67, fullname: "sdfdsfdf", email: "sonia647@yahoo.com"}
]
array = arrObj.filter((e, i, a) => a.map(E => E.groupId).indexOf(e.groupId) === i).map(el => arrObj.filter(EL => EL.groupId === el.groupId).length);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let array = []
let arrObj = [
              {groupId: 32, userId: 61, fullname: "Sonia M Russell", email: "sonia647@yahoo.com"},
              {groupId: 32, userId: 63, fullname: "zzzzdf Russell", email: "sonia647@yahoo.com"},
              {groupId: 43, userId: 65, fullname: "sdfsdf", email: "sonia647@yahoo.com"},
              {groupId: 59, userId: 67, fullname: "sdfdsfdf", email: "sonia647@yahoo.com"}
]

const result = arrObj.reduce((acc, value) => {
acc[value.groupId] = (acc[value.groupId] || 0) + 1;
return acc;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let array = Object.values(arrObj.reduce((acm, current) => {
    acm[current.groupId] = acm[current.groupId] || 0;
    acm[current.groupId] += 1;
    return acm;
}, {}))
```

Comment: i like this.  Probably could be abstracted to be a full pivot table ```pivot = (pivotBy, arrOfObj) => { /*...some stuff...*/ arrOfObj.reduce(pivotFunc, {}) /*...maybe some other stuff...*/ }```. and in usage ```pivotBy("groupId", arrObj)``` or pivot on two indexes (whihc would require more logic than you provided) ```pivotBy("groupId~fullname")```

Answer (score 1):

Can create a count function using `map/reduce` and update `count` of the id match then return the `values`.

```js
const count = (arr) => {
  return Object.values(arr.reduce((m, { groupId }) => {
    if (!m[groupId]) m[groupId] = 0;
    m[groupId] += 1
    return m
  },{}));
};

let arrObj =[{"groupId":32,"userId":61,"fullname":"Sonia M Russell","email":"sonia647@yahoo.com"},{"groupId":32,"userId":63,"fullname":"zzzzdf Russell","email":"sonia647@yahoo.com"},{"groupId":43,"userId":65,"fullname":"sdfsdf","email":"sonia647@yahoo.com"},{"groupId":59,"userId":67,"fullname":"sdfdsfdf","email":"sonia647@yahoo.com"}]

console.log(count(arrObj));
```

You can use `groupBy` function than `map` the `value length`.

```js
const groupBy = (arr, fn) =>
  arr
    .map(typeof fn === "function" ? fn : (val) => val[fn])
    .reduce((acc, val, i) => {
      acc[val] = (acc[val] || []).concat(arr[i]);
      return acc;
    }, {});
let arrObj =[{"groupId":32,"userId":61,"fullname":"Sonia M Russell","email":"sonia647@yahoo.com"},{"groupId":32,"userId":63,"fullname":"zzzzdf Russell","email":"sonia647@yahoo.com"},{"groupId":43,"userId":65,"fullname":"sdfsdf","email":"sonia647@yahoo.com"},{"groupId":59,"userId":67,"fullname":"sdfdsfdf","email":"sonia647@yahoo.com"}]

const grp = groupBy(arrObj, (x) => x.groupId);
const result = Object.values(grp).map((x) => x.length);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this by using `forEach`, maintain a hash for result set which will store the counter for groupId and loop through all elements in an array and then check if groupId already exists in a hash if it does then increment the counter by 1 else set it to 1.

```
let arrObj = [
     {groupId: 32, userId: 61, fullname: "Sonia M Russell", email: "sonia647@yahoo.com"},
     {groupId: 32, userId: 63, fullname: "zzzzdf Russell", email: "sonia647@yahoo.com"},
     {groupId: 43, userId: 65, fullname: "sdfsdf", email: "sonia647@yahoo.com"},
     {groupId: 53, userId: 67, fullname: "sdfdsfdf", email: "sonia647@yahoo.com"}
]

const result = {};
arrObj.forEach(e => {
    result[e.groupId] = (result[e.groupId] || 0) + 1;
});
console.log(Object.values(result));
```

jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/4ahef7mt/

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different technique that first uses `Set()` to determine the unique groupIds:

```js
let array = []
let arrObj = [{ groupId: 32, userId: 61, fullname: "Sonia M Russell", email: "sonia647@yahoo.com" }, { groupId: 32, userId: 63, fullname: "zzzzdf Russell", email: "sonia647@yahoo.com" }, { groupId: 43, userId: 65, fullname: "sdfsdf", email: "sonia647@yahoo.com" }, { groupId: 59, userId: 67, fullname: "sdfdsfdf", email: "sonia647@yahoo.com" } ];

// form set of unique Ids
const uniqueIds = new Set();
arrObj.forEach(obj => {
  uniqueIds.add(obj.groupId);
});

// form array of unique Id counts
uniqueIds.forEach(uid => {
  const reducer = (acc, curr) =>
    acc + Number(curr.groupId === uid);
  array.push(arrObj.reduce(reducer, 0));
});
console.log('array:', array);
```